# C: Stdin - Removing Excess Data

Tags: c, stdin, fflush

**Short version**

I want to get rid of excess user input from `stdin` but I understand `fflush(stdin)` is not recommended. I found this replacement:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

However, if there is no excess data to remove, this will remove the user's next input. How can I check if there is data to remove from `stdin` so I can choose whether or not to use this method of clearing the buffer?

**Long version with explanation**

I'm making a command-line tool in Obj-C/C.

I understand that declaring `char str[SIZE]` syntax allocates `SIZE` bytes of memory to `str`. I'd like to allocate as little memory as possible to each variable in order to avoid wasting memory.

However, if you use `fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin)` and you enter *more* than `SIZE` bytes of input, `fgets` will take `SIZE` bytes of your input and store that in `str`, leaving all the other data in the buffer. If you call `fgets` again, the remaining data will be stored in the variable you pass as `fgets`'s first variable and essentially skip the prompt completely. I don't want this to happen. A common solution is `fflush(stdin)`.

Various internet resources (including SO) state that using `fflush(stdin)` is not a good idea because it is "undefined" when you pass an input stream as argument.

I found this replacement on [CProgramming.com](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1044873249&id=1043284392)

```
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

However, the same source mentions that if there is no excess data in `stdin` to get rid of, it will do this with the user's next input, so the second time `fgets` is called it might not receive all the data.

How can I check if there is data in `stdin` so I can decide whether or not to clear it?

Comment: You can't really know if there is "excess" data in the input buffer. If you use e.g. [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to read input then most of the format skips leading whitespace, and for the two formats that doesn't you can solve it by inserting a leading space in the format.

Comment: And as for your worry about `fgets` not getting all, remember that `fgets` adds the ending newline to your buffer, so if the last character is a newline then you got the whole line, otherwise you have "excess" data.

Comment: You mean `if (getchar() != '\n') //there is excess data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read lines, and you're worried that you might not have read the whole line, remember that if [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) read the whole line the newline character should be the last character in the input buffer.

Example:

```
char smallBuffer[10];
while (fgets(smallBuffer, sizeof(smallBuffer), stdin) != NULL)
{
    if (strlen(smallBuffer) > 0)
    {
        // Check if we got the whole line
        if (smallBuffer[strlen(smallBuffer) - 1] == '\n')
        {
            // Yes, we got the whole line
        }
        else
        {
            // Whole line not read, there is still "excess" input
        }
    }
}
```