# Unexpected behavior from simple shell in C Debian Linux

Tags: c, linux, debian

The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80 /* Max command length */

int main(void)
{
   char fullCmd[MAX_LINE-1];
   const char *EXIT_CMD = "exit"; /* command to exit shell */
   int should_run = 1; /* flag to determine when to exit*/

   while (should_run)
   {
      printf("daw.0>");
      fflush(stdout);
      scanf("%s", fullCmd);

      if (strcmp(fullCmd, EXIT_CMD) == 0)
      {
         should_run = 0;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Results in the prompt (daw.0>) printing out repeatedly (the number of words - 1 times). For example, I I type in "Hello there everyone, how are you?", the following output is seen:

```
daw.0>Hello there everyone, how are you?

daw.0>
daw.0>
daw.0>
daw.0>
daw.0>
daw.0>
```

I don't understand why.  I have a lot more that I need to do to create a shell for an assignment, but I can't even get the simplest variation to work reliably.  I am using a Debian distribution of Linux in Virtual Box.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Use the debugger `gdb`. Read an entire line (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33047835/841108)...) then parse it later.

Comment: `%s` reads one word, not one line.

Comment: Off-topice here. We won't do your homework for you. BTW, you really should study the source code of some existing shell... (they all are free software)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scanf()` with `%s` stops scanning at the first whitespace. That explains the behaviour you observe.

What you probably wanted to use is [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html). Be aware that `fgets()` reads in the newline as well if there's sufficient space available in the buffer. If this is something you don't want then you have to remove the trailing newline (if any).

Comment: Guess I was too slow. But I might as well add in the [doc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). In the middle it says that `s   Matches a sequence of non-white-space characers`

Comment: @Arc676 Thanks! Added the link too.

Comment: I recommend `getline` or `readline`, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33047835/841108). `fgets` (which forces a limit on the maximal length of the line) should only be used when you don't have `getline`, which exists on all POSIX systems.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Never knew about `readline`. Cool function.

Comment: "Be aware that `fgets()` reads the newline as well". [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25526856/c-stdin-removing-excess-data) is some extra information on removing the newline as well as removing the excess data in STDIN to prevent the prompt from appearing too many times.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch just adding `fgets()` should *also* be used (maybe in the context of a `getline()`-replacing function) if you care about (possibly later) portability to non-POSIX systems, so it's basically a design issue. Still good hint!

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  I replaced scanf() with getline() and things are working great now.